# Считать количество записей по месяцам

Tags: php, mysql

Как составить SQL запрос который бы заходил в таблицу и считал количество записей по месяцам. Ну то есть в таблицу есть записи допустим: id - 1, name - test, date - 2014-01-01;
id - 2, name - test2, date - 2014-02-01; Нужно посчитать количество записей по месяцам и обновить число в другой таблице в которой структура Месяц - число.
Вот изображения первая таблица откуда надо посчитать

[image: Imgur]

вторая таблица где нужно обновить число

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(date),COUNT(*)
FROM table1
GROUP BY MONTHNAME(date)
```

со вставкой сам разберешься

Answer (score 0):

во второй таблице нужно сделать идентификатор месяца 01,02,03,04..,12
делать

```
BETWEEN year(now())+'-'tble2.id_month+'-'+01 AND year(now())+'-'tble2.id_month+'-'+31
```

Ну а что делать дальше я думаю вы разберётесь!